# Convert cost function into quadratic constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, operations-research

> [image: Problem Picture]
>
> [image: My objective function and constraints]

I've provided the problem and the objective function and constraints I wrote. I'm having problems changing the objective function into quadratic constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed up the conditions for the constraints and the objective function.

For the objective function, you want to minimize the $l_1$ distance, of which it can be converted to a linear form.

For the constraints, we should use $l_2$ distance for the antenna constraint